# Forcing usermod with running program

Tags: bash

I've been looking for a way to force usermod to modify the password/group/... files despite the user being in use.

What I do get now is this:

```
!! Failed to execute 'usermod --home '...' --password '...' --shell '/bin/false' 'zabbix' 2>&1':
usermod: user zabbix is currently used by process 518
```

I know that for being secure I need to restart the service. But this is done within a setup script. I am restarting all services at the end.

Is there any way to say --force? (well, except for modifying all necessary files.)

Thanks

Comment: it may be actually simpler to just modify the files. Or run pkill -u ${user} and then the usermod

Comment: To change the user's home and default shell, it is easy enough to modify `/etc/passwd`: that file is very script-friendly.  To change the password, try running `passwd` directly.

Comment: Here's an line that will generate a new `passwd` with home and shell replaced: `awk -F: '/^username:/ { print $1":"$2":"$3":"$4":/new/home:/new/shell"; next} {print $0}'`

Comment: Ok, seems no way to change it unless I do it via files, or kill the program :-(. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

If you can get root rights via sudo and are confident enough to change system files using vi then I would change the files manually.

Only a few things need to be changed in

```
- /etc/passwd
  here you could change UID, GID, Homedirectory, Shell ...
- /etc/group
  here you might need to change UID/GID as well for the username if there was a change
```

The File /etc/shadow will be changed automatically when using passwd to set a new password. This you can directly perform if you are root: "passwd username"

Answer (score 0):

You can run `usermod` in a separate user namespace (with a recent enough linux), but you need to map the root user to root (otherwise you won't have permissions to modify `/etc/passwd`).

I.e. something like this:

```
unshare --user --map-root-user usermod ...
```

Now usermod won't find the processes running with the uid of user you are modifying.

You probably won't be able to modify the root user itself with this.

Comment: This will not work in WSL2 https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2981  you're forced to change the /etc/passwd file directory if you're in WSL2